# Why can't i use functions like ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC'); in my custom model?

Tags: magento

I had created a custom model which uses ORM, i tried out "Weblog" example in the link http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics and i was able to retrieve values from db using collection, but i cannot use functions like "->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');" with my collection object.

Are these functions specific only to product model such as "catalog/product"? if so how could i use such filtering capabilities to my custom function?

Thank you very much..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions are specific to EAV models. Otherwise you are limited to the 'field' equivalents like `addFieldToFilter()` and `addOrder()`.

To make your custom model use an EAV resource read the rest of that tutorial, especially [part 7](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-7-advanced-orm-entity-attribute-value).

Answer (score 1):

you can use functionally of setOrder('$attribute','ASC')
to reorder

Comment: Ok is there any functions for using like,in,join etc., is there any online documentation available to perform functions like these in simple model? if so it would be helpful...